# Why does Golang only save %rsp, %rip and %rbp(no other callee-saved registers) when switch context?

Tags: go, x86-64, goroutine, calling-convention, context-switch

In general user-thread context switch implementations(like `setjmp/longjmp` and the `function return` way), we save and restore callee-saved registers, but golang only save and restore `%rsp`, `%rip` and `%rbp` in [gobuf](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/runtime2.go#L310).

Take x86_64 as example, golang save the goroutine context with [runtime.gosave](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s#L252) and restore goroutine context with [runtime.gogo](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s#L272).

So why does golang do it in this way?

Comment: IIRC it uses stack-args even on x86-64, not the x86-64 System V ABI.  Are those the only call-preserved registers in Go's custom calling convention (that it uses for any normal functions)?  Or does it have some way of indicating that the call to `runtime.gosave` will clobber all other registers, forcing the caller to save them in that one case.  I don't use go so I can't easily check; hopefully someone who knows Go's ABI and design can answer your question more easily.

Comment: This might be historic from the first compiler.. Note that there is no need to save/restore the other registers.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. It does have relation with golang ABI. As Ian said `Well, sort of.  In the current ports there are no callee-saved
registers other than the frame pointer.` https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/golang-dev/HDLMMYQv7Ak

Comment: Yuck, what a nasty calling convention.  Does the compiler inline very aggressively to make sure there are no tight loops with a small function call inside them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently GoLang still uses an inefficient calling convention where **the only call-preserved (aka non-volatile) registers are RSP and RBP.**

A call to `runtime.gosave` looks to the compiler like any other function call (i.e. it eventually returns after doing some stuff, and doesn't modify anything above its own stack frame).  Like any other function call, the caller has to assume it destroys all the call-clobbered (volatile) registers (everything except RSP and RBP).  Thus any values it wants to survive the call have to be spilled to stack slots (or other memory location where they belong).

For the same reason, C `setjmp` only has to save the call-preserved registers.  And kernel context-switch functions are the same.

---

This 2017 [google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/golang-dev/HDLMMYQv7Ak) says that's how its calling convention / ABI works, and from the linked code it looks like that still hasn't been improved.

Go's calling convention also inefficiently passes all args on the stack, unlike the x86-64 System V ABI which passes the first 6 integer args (and first 8 FP) in registers.